# Почему не работает авторизация на сайте с сессиями и cookie?

Tags: php, cookie, curl, парсер, сессия

Добрый вечер.

Не получается с помощью cURL пройти авторизацию. Вроде все верно делаю, а все равно не пускает.

Вот сайт - http://www.vezetvsem.ru/listing
Вот форма авторизации - https://auth.vezetvsem.ru/auth/login

Скрытых полей нет. Логин/пароль верные.
Для теста можно пользовать эти:
Login: 6kp5228wi4@kismail.ru
Pass: w33q5u8t

После отработки кода, получаем код с неавторизованной страницы.

```
<?
function login($url,$login,$pass){

   $ch = curl_init();
   if(strtolower((substr($url,0,5))=='https')) { // если соединяемся с https
  //моя вставка
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
  //моя вставка
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   // откуда пришли на эту страницу
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   // cURL будет выводить подробные сообщения о всех производимых действиях
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=".$login."&password=".$pass);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   echo "username=".$login."&password=".$pass;
   //сохранять полученные COOKIE в файл
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
   $result=curl_exec($ch);


   // Убеждаемся что произошло перенаправление после авторизации
   if(strpos($result,"Location: home.php")===false) die('Login incorrect');

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}

// чтение страницы после авторизации
function Read($url){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
   // откуда пришли на эту страницу
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   //запрещаем делать запрос с помощью POST и соответственно разрешаем с помощью GET
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   //отсылаем серверу COOKIE полученные от него при авторизации
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}



$urlAut = "https://auth.vezetvsem.ru/auth/login";

login($urlAut,"6kp5228wi4@kismail.ru","w33q5u8t");

$page = Read("http://www.vezetvsem.ru/listing");

echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: за Вас код писать не будут) Вам на http://fl.ru

Comment: Так я не прошу код за меня писать. Я прошу указать в чем конкретно у меня ошибка? Функция написана по канонам с учебников с разных сайтов. Авторизацию должна проходить, а по факту не проходит. Где копать уже и не знаю прям.

Comment: предоставить логин и пароль от vezetvsem сможете?

Comment: @ikerya Конечно. Я для этих задач как раз сделал тестовый. Login 6kp5228wi4@kismail.ru
Pass w33q5u8t Не понимаю, почему не работает, так как подставляя данные для друго сайта, где есть еще 2 скрытых поля (которое несложно извлечь этим же способом), все работает.

Comment: Почему Вы решили что не работает? У меня возвращается именно авторизованная страница. Вопрос в том для чего Вам вот это нужно? `if(strpos($result,"Location: home.php")===false) die('Login incorrect');`

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать программирование. Пока за месяц нахватался из разных мест поверхностных знаний по  HTML CSS. Совсем крапаль JS. Немного о форме Ajax. PHP недели 2 изучаю, разные курсы, начиная от специласта, и заканичвая статьями в интернете. ООП и прочие вещи совсем пока не понимаю. Поверхностно вник в регулярные выражения и как они работают, Simple HTML DOM не осилил под свою задачу. Поверхностно MySQL. Чуть чуть библиотеку CURL.Теперь все эти знания пытаюсь собрать в реально рабочий проект парсера сайта торгов, с выводом информации с учетом собственных фильтров.

Comment: @ikerya При выполнении кода получаю в переменной $page неавторизованную страницу. (при условии что строка, что вы указали закоментирована, так как я пока не понимаю что она делает. ) Код был взят с другого портала и адаптирован, так как самописная версия на vezetvsem работать не хочет. А этот код хвалят. 1-ая функция получает куки и записывает их. Вторая использует их и по идеи все должно работать. Но не работает. Я честно скажу, что CURL и как это все работает, пока для меня темный лес, пытаюсь разобраться. Сюда написал в надежед на примерный вектор проблемы, чтобы покапав,понять где я ошибся

Comment: @ikerya Абсолютно не понимаю, почему функция Read() не работает, и возвращает неавторизованную страницу, но нашел решение через другую функцию. Когда проект закончу, и подучу мат часть, попробую разобраться в своей ошибке. Сейчас пока все работает=) Спасибо большое за уделенное время. Ваш комментарий выше вдохновил меня на поиск альтернативного пути.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря пользователям вдохновился на ипользование иной функции. В итоге получился вот такой код, который работает.Спасибо большое за помощь.
*Приношу извинение за плохой код, я всего лишь месяц самоучка.*

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   if(strtolower((substr($url,0,5))=='https')) { // если соединяемся с https
  //моя вставка
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
  //моя вставка
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   // откуда пришли на эту страницу
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   // cURL будет выводить подробные сообщения о всех производимых действиях
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=".$login."&password=".$pass);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   //сохранять полученные COOKIE в файл
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookievezetvsem.txt');
   $result=curl_exec($ch);


   // Убеждаемся что произошло перенаправление после авторизации
   //if(strpos($result,"Location: home.php")===false) die('Login incorrect'); // для чего нужен этот код и как он работает?

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}

// чтение страницы после авторизации
function Read($url){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
   // откуда пришли на эту страницу
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   //запрещаем делать запрос с помощью POST и соответственно разрешаем с помощью GET
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   //отсылаем серверу COOKIE полученные от него при авторизации
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookievezetvsem.txt');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}


function mainParser( $url )// парсер с кукисами
{

  $ch = curl_init( $url );

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // возвращает веб-страницу
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);           // не возвращает заголовки
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   // переходит по редиректам
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");        // обрабатывает все кодировки
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");  // useragent
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookievezetvsem.txt'); //хотя тут скорей всего он не записывает, а после каждого прохода вновь обращается к этому файлу 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // таймаут соединения
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        // таймаут ответа
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);       // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа


  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  $header['errno']   = $err;
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  $header['content'] = $content;
  return $header;
}


$urlAut = "https://auth.vezetvsem.ru/auth/login";

login($urlAut,"XXX","XXX");
//login($urlAut,"6kp5228wi4@kismail.ru","w33q5u8t"); // по непонятной причине, эта пара Login, пароль возвращает неавторизованную страницу, Почему, я не понимаю.

//$result = Read("http://www.vezetvsem.ru/listing"); // по какой то причине эта функция не работает, почему, я пока не понимаю



$result = mainParser("http://www.vezetvsem.ru/listing");
$page = $result['content'];
echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: 1. Функция Read() выдает неавторизованную страницу т.к. был указан отличный useragent от функции login(), 2. Данные указаные в вопросе перестали работать. Кто-то их поменял, либо сайт заблокировал аккаунт по причине выхода из разных мест. Благо аккаунт был тестовый и зареган на выдуманные данные. 3. Для чего нужна строка if(strpos($result,"Location: home.php")===false) die('Login incorrect');` и почему она выдает ошибку осталось не ясным.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел отправку запроса.
он отправляется методом Post

`Request URL:https://auth.vezetvsem.ru/auth/login
Request Method:POST`

а вы пытаетесь скормить ему данные GET-ом.

поле login передается вместе с формой , это значение менять не нужно 
`username:6kp5228wi4@kismail.ru
 password:w33q5u8t
 login:Войти`

попробуйте так :

```
     $data = array('username' => username, 'password' => password, login =>Войти);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT  5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: К сожалению, вы ошиблись. Вот заголовок передаваемой формы POST запросом https://www.dropbox.com/s/wju4htlxnl7dd13/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202016-06-29%2016.26.40.png?dl=0 В самом низу там как раз то, что передается браузером. Решение нашел, подставив немного измененный код из другой функции. Ниже отпишусь. Но огромное спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: @Олег, пожалуй не соглашусь с вами , что я ошибся :) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkekas3ohjfpu9r/auth.png?dl=0

там есть 2 формы авторизации, потому так и получилось

Comment: полностью с Вами согласен. Непонятно зачем вторая форам нужна. Как подучу мат часть попробую разобраться. В любом случае еще раз огромное вам спасибо за уделенное время.